# Immediately stop a while loop when value is false

Tags: lua

I have a while loop and I want it to IMMEDIATELY stop when a value is false.
I'm guessing that if I just do this:

```
while value == true do
    print("bla")
    wait(2)
    print("blaaaaa")
end
```

Then it'll keep doing the while loop including (including the wait) until the end.
Is this true? If so, how do I fix this?

**Edit:** snippet of my actual code:

```
function GM:PlayerDisconnected(ply)
    if table.Count(Players) == 1 then
        reset()
    end
end

function GM:PlayerAuthed(ply, steamID, uID)
    if not playing then
      if table.Count(Players) == 2 then
          --Woo hoo start game
          while playing do

          end
      end
    end
end

function reset()
    playing = false

    for k,v in pairs(player.GetAll()) do
        v:Kill()
        v:SetGameModeTeam(2)
    end

    chat.AddText("There needs to be 2 players!")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a break statement.. something like

```
if (your condition) then break end
```

I assume that you want the loop to stop when playing is false. In that case replace

```
while playing do

end
```

with

```
while playing do

    if table.Count(Players) < 2
    then
        break
    end
end
```

The moment the break statement is executed (i.e the moment there are less then two players) the while loop will exit. You should only have to put this if statement in your loop once. Probably at the end of your loop. I can't say for sure because I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I have to add that before every single line? That sounds tedious

Comment: @NathanEllis: If you would have to check for a loop end condition after every single line then you are using the loop in a wrong way. It might be that a loop is not the right thing to use in your case, or, that you have to rethink how to approach the problem. Please explain what your use case is and what you want to do.

Comment: I'm making a GMod gamemode (coded in lua) that requires 2 players, and if a player leaves, then I want the entire gamemode to stop. I already have everything working, but I want it to stop when the player count is under 2

Comment: @NathanEllis Can you add the relevant code snippets as an example to your question to better illustrate what you're after? Not the whole thing mind you, just the important parts.

Comment: not really @NathanEllis ; what's between `while playing do ... end`?